# jQuery: Add class if LI has checked radio box

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to add a class to a `<li>` if it contains a checked radio button.

This is my current HTML structure:

```
<li class="wc_payment_method payment_method_paypal">
    <input id="payment_method_paypal" type="radio" class="input-radio" name="payment_method" value="paypal">
    <label for="payment_method_paypal">PayPal</label>
</li>
```

And this is what I've tried so far:

```
<script>
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $(".wc_payment_method :checked").each(function() {
            $(this).addClass("is-checked");
            alert(this.id + " is checked");
        });
    });

</script>
```

The alert works. It shows the correct `<li>` item with a checked radio button.
But there are two problems I couldn't solve.

1. The scripts doesn't add the class `is-checked` on page load
2. The alert doesn't work anymore if I select an other radio button.

Could anybody push me in the right direction?

Comment: Put a change event handler on the radio buttons.

Comment: Your code adds the class to the checkbox, not the DIV.

Comment: Also just to point out, nothing in this logic is going to remove the class if the radio selection changes.  It's only adding the class.

Comment: @Taplar you're right. Noticed it a minute ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want classes to change when you check or uncheck the boxes, you need an event handler. The handler can check whether each LI contains a checked button.

```js
$(".wc_payment_method :radio").click(function() {
  $(".wc_payment_method").each(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("is-checked", $(this).find(":radio:checked").length > 0);
  });
});
```

```css
.is-checked {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="wc_payment_method payment_method_paypal">
    <input id="payment_method_paypal" type="radio" class="input-radio" name="payment_method" value="paypal">
    <label for="payment_method_paypal">PayPal</label>
  </li>
  <li class="wc_payment_method payment_method_credit">
    <input id="payment_method_credit" type="radio" class="input-radio" name="payment_method" value="credit">
    <label for="payment_method_paypal">Credit Card</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks, in my case it's a `<li>` not a `<div>`. So I've changed every `div` in your code to `li`. But the code has no effect :(

Comment: You wrote **add a class to a <div>**

Comment: I didn't notice that it was a radio button, not a checkbox.

Comment: OK, the code works if I use it on a blank example. But the class stays if I uncheck the radio button. And in my code it doesn't work. But that's not the fault of your answer

Comment: Fixed it. I was still assuming checkboxes.

Comment: that's it! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your code add a class only to the input tags. 
To add a specific class on click event you must use $().click metod from jquery.

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
function addClass() {
 $(".wc_payment_method input:checked").each(function() {
  $(this).closest('li').addClass('yourClass');
  $(this).addClass("is-checked");
  alert(this.id + " is checked");
 });
}
addClass();

$(".wc_payment_method input").click(function(){
 addClass();
});
});
```

```html
<script
     src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js"
     integrity="sha256-xNzN2a4ltkB44Mc/Jz3pT4iU1cmeR0FkXs4pru/JxaQ="
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<ul>
<li class="wc_payment_method payment_method_paypal">
    <input id="payment_method_paypal" type="radio" class="input-radio" checked name="payment_method" value="paypal">
    <label for="payment_method_paypal">PayPal</label>
</li>

<li class="wc_payment_method payment_method_paypal1">
    <input id="payment_method_paypal1" type="radio" class="input-radio" name="payment_method1" value="paypal2">
    <label for="payment_method_paypal1">PayPal</label>
</li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Stack snippet has separate boxes for HTML and JavaScript, separate your code into them.

Comment: @Barmar sorry, it was only a test, I m new here and I only want to check how it's work.